# Replace the word ostentatiousness

Tags: single-word-requests

I say to my friend,

> I am an extremely good cook! Please forgive me: no bragging intended here!

What I'm trying to do is to say the same thought but using a different world:
*ostentatiousness*.

"I'm saying this Without any ostentatiousness"
or should I add the word;
I'm saying this Without any ostentatiousness intended "

Comment: A good noun from *ostentatious* is *ostentation.* Does that fit? Please have a look at our [help for single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and particularly the checklist at the bottom.

Comment: So the intent is to ironically be ostentatious?

Comment: What's wrong with your original phrasing? *No bragging* seems more natural and conversational. Is there some reason you want to replace *bragging*? (Because if you hadn't already used it, it would be a natural suggestion to replace *ostentatiousness*.) Note that *brag* is also a noun. *And that's not a brag.*

Answer (score 1):

**braggadocio** 
could potentially work well:

> Boastful or arrogant behaviour
>
> *I'm saying this without any **braggadocio***

Re Andrew Leach's comment:

**ostentation**

> The pretentious or showy display of wealth and luxury, designed to impress.
>
> *I'm saying this without any **ostentation***

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/braggadocio) and [ODO.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ostentation)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one. Use the adjective

- I am saying this without any ostentatious display of vanity.

Or simply

- No ostentation intended

Answer (score 0):

**Ostentation** is the making of success, wealth, power, etc, visible. Wearing an expensive watch or suit, driving an expensive car, prominent display of trophies or certificates,  etc. Informing people in speech or writing of one's high opinion of one's own abilities is commonly called **boasting**. In many cultures, the perception of boastfulness cannot be cancelled by the speaker's use of a form of words such as "no boasting intended here". Boastfulness, in short, is in the ear of the hearer. There is a modern conversational tactic called 'humblebragging' where boasting or bragging is disguised by humble phrasing.

[Ostentation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ostentation)
[Boasting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boasting)
[Humblebrag](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humblebrag)